# About removing the reputation of suggested-edits and put that reputation to find duplicates

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, exact-duplicates, suggested-edits

In the context of the [current situation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34779/what-does-low-quality-contributions-mean-and-who-decides-this), and also, time ago [situation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?noredirect=1&lq=1), in part for the duplicate-questions on math.SE,

Could it be that, perhaps temporarily, the +2 reputation for the suggested edits be "switched" to find duplicates?

Comment: I think this is worth considering. Too many users suggest superficial edits, or attempt to "beautify" already well-formatted question, to earn two points.  Edits to capitalize every word in the title, e.g., and so much more.  Even when suggested edits violate the FAQ Xander posted on suggested edits, if such an editor rants on meta, users trying to abide by Xander's suggestions get scorned.  I'd rather 2 points be awarded to dupe finds, which do not lend themselves to "opinionated" claims of "valid edits".  It seems far more objective to evaluate a dupe suggestion.

Comment: A related older post: [A possible solution to reduce answering of duplicate questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33204). (In the comments you can see some posts on [meta.se] with similar suggestions.)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Even on meta.stackexchange posts, there is a lot of support. The detractors' main arguments are (1) That people may wrongly tag duplicates while chasing rep. I don't know the scale of this problem (2) That having "some" number of duplicates around is good. This is Jeff Atwood's argument, and it definitely doesn't hold true in a situation where we've got 100 questions proof-verifying "rationals are countable" or something. All in all, I'm basically for positive incentivization in the direction of repository-building, be it reputation, badges, whatever.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Ah yes, it's similar. The point here is  to help to reduce the current problems on the linked posts

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer aha, the badges are another. This was an idea, but it could be modified. For example, more points, a new privilege (original, not one of the current ones), etc.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I'll add that a badge for this purpose was briefly discussed here: [Encouraging duplicate hunters](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31192). (Again, the comments contain some links to [meta.se].)

Comment: Thank you for the replies, Martin and @VeronicaR.M. Yes editing is important , but right now I think duplication should be seen as a bigger issue and should be controlled better. I spend a lot of time finding duplicates (and inefficiently to my standards, at that) but not much time editing. Editing is pretty much an algorithm , at least for me : MathJax, grammar, spacing, it's almost routine and is confined to the post in question. On the other hand, duplicate-searching requires scouring MSE , and if one includes abstract duplicates, it's not completely a search-engine job either.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Ah. Well let's see how this goes, first this need the community support and then the SE support, which I don't know how difficult could that be (codings?). I could also notice that this is a some time ago problem, at least from [2](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31192/) years ago.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer But indeed I agree that the +2 aren't that "equivalent" as for the editing... and also, it takes more time.

Comment: As I’ve said before, I like the idea. A couple of things: 1. Why only reward edits or duplicates? Why not both? I’m not really sure why the two are connected. 2. I’d also say, go bigger. Finding duplicates is often more work than editing. We could, for example, award 5 points if the dupe target you’ve found is included in the list of dupe targets, and, perhaps even 10 points if your dupe target is accepted by the OP (I see it as a similar situation to giving an answer that is accepted).

Comment: @TheoBendit That sounds good :) You could either continue this, or perhaps make a new post and talk about it ^^

Comment: @VeronicaR.M. No, I think your proposal is of sufficient merit to get behind as it is now. Have my +1.

Comment: This seems peripheral to the actual question at hand, but it seems implausible to me that a user would suggest edits with the primary intention of earning reputation. Getting just a single upvote on a question/answer has the same effect as having 5 suggested edits accepted.

Comment: @Joe I don't think it's because of the reputation per se, but the subjective reward.